# Syntax for class constructors

Tags: haskell

I have this code:

```
data SafeValue a = SafeValue a a a deriving Eq

class Safe a where
  check::a->Bool
  (+++)::a->a->a

instance (Num a, Eq a) => Safe (SafeValue a) where
  check (SafeValue x y z) | x == y = True
                          | x == z = True
                          | y == z = True
                          | otherwise = False
  (SafeValue a b c)+++(SafeValue x y z) = let new_val = SafeValue (a+x) (b+y) (c+z)
                                          in if check new_val then new_val
                                                              else error "Error"
```

I would like to add to `class Safe` a function such as:

```
make_new 3 --> SafeValue 3 3 3
```

I don't know how to add it, since the tipy should be something like:

```
make_new::b->a
```

but in the `istance` declaration `ghci` claims that it is not sure about what `b` is.

Can someone help, please?

Comment: Why are you using typeclasses anyways... You should just define functions check and (+++)

Comment: yes, that is maybe the best thing to do...

Comment: Dont mix type classes with classes of imperative programming. Type classes can be thought of like interfaces of Java (if you are from imperative background), which I dont think you need here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The core problem is that you're promising that `make_new` works for *all* types `b` to produce a value of `a`. However, this doesn't make sense given how `SafeValue a` works: given some type `a`, you get a `SafeValue a` out. So what you really want is for `make_new` to take a value of some type `a` but give you a value of `SafeValue a`. More generally, you want the result to be of some type `s a` where `s` is the actual type you're writing an instance for and `a` can be *any* type.

What you need to do is make the class accept values of a "higher-kinded" type. (What this means is that the class should expect a type like `SafeValue` that takes a further parameter. You can do that like this:

```
class Safe s where
  check :: s a -> Bool
  (+++) :: s a -> s a -> s a
  make_new :: a ->  s a
```

Then your instance will look like this:

```
instance Safe SafeValue where ...
```

Note the important difference: instead of making an instance for `SafeValue a`, you're making on for `SafeValue` *without* the type parameter.

However, this has another problem: now you cannot constrain `a` to be part of `Num` and `Eq`!

You can solve this with an extension called multi-parameter type classes. So your final version would be:

```
class Safe s a where
  check :: s a -> Bool
  (+++) :: s a -> s a -> s a
  make_new :: a -> s a
```

and your instance would be:

```
instance (Num a, Eq a) => Safe SafeValue a where ...
```

To make all this work, you need to enable two extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
```

The first one lets you write instances in more ways. Normally, you can only write instances for a type that looks like `T a b c` where `T` is a type and `a b c` are type variables; with this extension, the restriction is lifted and you can write instances like the one I showed.

The multiparameter typeclass extension allows typeclasses that act on more than one type. This allows you to make a class that depends on both `s` *and* `a`.

A final note: using typeclasses at all may not be the right choice for your example. Are you planning to write any more types for the `Safe` class? If you aren't, then you shouldn't use a typeclass at all. However, learning a bit about multiparameter typeclasses is still useful, so you should consider playing around with them at some point.

Comment: Alternately, instead of using MPTCs, you can put the `Eq` constraint on `check` and the `Num/Eq` constraint on `(+++)`, e.g. `class Safe s where check :: Eq a => s a -> Bool` or something like that.

Comment: @DanielWagner a "better" way, perhaps, would be to allow each instance to specify the necessary constraints on each operation. Some types might be able to implement `check` and `+++` without constraining `a`. I believe this is possible with the new kind extensions, but am unsure how to actually do it.